# LiqtoTwitter Authorization Automation

Tags: automation, authorization, linq-to-twitter

is it ever possible to authorize twitter app on the desktop without user input (of the seven digit number)?
I am trying to develop a realtime tweet fetching application between  a list of friends/followers "suspects" communicating together. But the authorization code that needs to reset after 15 mins is an issue, so unless someone if manually present to handle re authorization after a couple of mins is a serious challenging. Is there a solution to my question.

Joe Mayo or any one, pls help here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two different issues at work here: authorization and 15 minute rate limit windows. For authorization, you receive OAuthToken and AccessToken, accessible via IAuthorizer.Credentials after the user authorizes. These tokens never expire. So, you save them when the user first authorizes and then load them into IAuthorizer.Credentials and you won't need to perform authorization again. Here's a more detailed description:

[linqtotwitter - grab the saved credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542146/linqtotwitter-grab-the-saved-credentials/22548019#22548019)

Since you mentioned something about "reset after 15 mins", I assume you're referring to Rate Limits, which are set in 15 minute windows. Here's a recent discussion:

[How to handle LinqtoTwitter Rate(v2.1) limit exceeded Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959972/how-to-handle-linqtotwitter-ratev2-1-limit-exceeded-error/22972005#22972005)

It would be helpful to review the Twitter docs on [Rate Limiting](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1).